# Broken git autocompletion after I have overridden the git command

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete, git

Recently `git branch <tab>` started showing me the following error:

```
$ git branch bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `/usr/bin/git --git-dir=.git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes'
HEAD bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `/usr/bin/git --git-dir=.git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes'
HEAD ^C
```

How can I fix it?

I have the following lines in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
git() {
    cmd=$1
    shift
    extra=""

    quoted_args=""
    whitespace="[[:space:]]"
    for i in "$@"
    do
        if [[ $i =~ $whitespace ]]
        then
            i=\"$i\"
        fi
        quoted_args="$quoted_args $i"
    done

    cmdToRun="`which git` "$cmd" $quoted_args"
    cmdToRun=`echo $cmdToRun | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'`
    bash -c "$cmdToRun"
    # Some mad science here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not preserve quotes. The original line executed by completion is:

```
git --git-dir=.git for-each-ref '--format=%(refname:short)' refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes
```

by your script you get:

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/git --git-dir=.git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) refs/tags refs/heads refs/remotes'
```

***Note the missing quotes around:***

```
--format=%(refname:short)
```

---

Have not looked at what you actually do, but this:

```
quoted_args="$quoted_args \"$i\""
#                         |  |
#                         +--+------- Extra quotes.
```

should result in something like:

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/git --git-dir=.git "for-each-ref" "--format=%(refname:short)" "refs/tags" "refs/heads" "refs/remotes"'
```

or:

```
quoted_args="$quoted_args '$i'"
#                         |  |
#                         +--+------- Extra quotes.

bash -c '/usr/bin/git --git-dir=.git '\''for-each-ref'\'' '\''--format=%(refname:short)'\'' '\''refs/tags'\'' '\''refs/heads'\'' '\''refs/remotes'\'''
```

---

You might want to look into the `%q` format for `printf`.

Comment: That's awesome. I removed the `if` from the `for` loop and used `quoted_args="$quoted_args \"$i\""` instead. Thanks a lot!